# How can I sync audio from an mp3 audio track and Blu-ray video?

Tags: audio, blu-ray, vcd

I have a Blu-ray source of a English movie, and I have bought a local language dubbed version of the same movie but it is VCD quality. I want to show the movie in Blu-ray definition to my friends but they can't understand English, so I extracted the audio track of the local language dubbed VCD version as mp3 and used Convert X to DVD to add another audio track to the movie and create a DVD out of it. However, I found out that the audio of the VCD audio track is not in Sync with the video of the Blu-ray video. It's not offset just a few seconds earlier or delayed, but it is not in sync in random ways, most likely due to frames per second or mp3 bitrate difference between the Blu-ray version and the VCD version.

So, is it possible to change my VCD audio track file, which is in mp3 format, to match the Blu-ray video? Can this be done by changing bitrate, etc.?

Comment: please any ideas ?